# JHipster deploy Pivotal Web Services - AutoConfigure cycle detected

Tags: spring, jhipster, pivotal-web-services

I wanted to deploy my JHipster (5.1.0) on Pivotal Web Services. Locally `./mvnw -pprod` worked well with my MySQL database. I had no issues. Once I want to deploy my application on the Pivotal Web Services I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: AutoConfigure cycle detected between org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration

Did I forget anything? I'm really struggling with this exception. Spring Boot 2.0.3 is used

Comment: Maybe a property missing in your app*.yml or wrong spring profile ? Have you checked profiles in your logs?

Comment: The logs show cloud and prod profile. Here is my prod profile yml: https://jsfiddle.net/mnwstoyz/ I just changed the names and passwords.

Comment: You could try to debug Spring Boot AutoConfiguration, add `debug: true` to your app*yml and see what you get in logs.

Comment: I set the RAM and the space to 2G each but it logs the following error: http://snippi.com/s/4dscqs4

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I just tried to run the war on my own computer and got the following exception : http://snippi.com/s/2ybq0ys

Comment: That error can be caused by having conflicting Spring Boot versions on the classpath. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75668959/3059685