# Eclipse Spring Boot - AutoConfigure cycle detected between HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration and CacheAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I am using injecting some other projects in my service . But while integrating them I am facing below exception : 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: AutoConfigure cycle detected between org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration

All of the projects which I am injecting in my main project are built on spring-boot 2.1.3

What can fix this issue.
Please let me know if any other information required regarding this.

Below are the logs that are generated while running the service :

```
*

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)

2019-05-23 19:49:08.398  INFO 12596 --- [           main] c.k.r.m.KmartMasterServiceApplication    : Starting KmartMasterServiceApplication on ******* with PID (started by athora0 in C:\Users\******\Documents\Migration Project\ababba)
2019-05-23 19:49:08.402  INFO 12596 --- [           main] c.k.r.m.KmartMasterServiceApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-05-23 19:49:09.691 ERROR 12596 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: AutoConfigure cycle detected between org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.doSortByAfterAnnotation(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:92) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.doSortByAfterAnnotation(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:95) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.sortByAnnotation(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:78) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.getInPriorityOrder(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:67) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.sortAutoConfigurations(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:461) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:442) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:881) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:804) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:774) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [mastersignprevention-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.kmart.res.master_service.KmartMasterServiceApplication.main(KmartMasterServiceApplication.java:28) [classes/:na]*
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by conflicting versions of the Spring Boot libraries in your classpath (see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9278#issuecomment-303077249)

In my case, I had an IntelliJ project that run using the cucumber cli (Cucumber Java plugin). IntelliJ was putting both version 2.0.2.RELEASE and version 2.0.5.RELEASE of the Spring Boot libraries in my classpath.

If I ran the same project with gradle bootRun it resolved the dependencies correctly and only put the 2.0.5.RELEASE libraries on my classpath. Thus the cycle error did not occur.

The solution to allow running with the cucumber cli was to add the Spring Boot starter 2.0.5.RELEASE dependency to the *build.gradle* file for the module I was running in (it was a multi-module project). This removed the 2.0.2.RELEASE libraries from the classpath.